# Generating dummy data from existing data set is slow using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to generate dummy data from the existing data I have in the tables. All I want is to increase the number of records in Table1 to N specified amount. The other tables should increase based on the foreign key references.

The tables has one to many relationship. For one record in table 1, I can have multiple entries in table 2, and in table 3 I can have many records based on IDs of the second table.

Since IDs are primary keys, I either capture it by

```
SET @NEWLY_INSERTED_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

after inserting to table 1 and using in insert for table2, or inserting them to temp table and joining them to achieve the same results for table 3.

Here's the approach I'm taking with the `CURSOR`.

```
DECLARE @MyId as INT;
DECLARE @myCursor as CURSOR;

DECLARE @DESIRED_ROW_COUNT INT = 70000
DECLARE @ROWS_INSERTED INT = 0
DECLARE @CURRENT_ROW_COUNT INT = 0
DECLARE @NEWLY_INSERTED_ID INT
DECLARE @LANGUAGE_PAIR_IDS TABLE ( LangugePairId INT, NewId INT, SourceLanguage varchar(100), TargetLangauge varchar(100) )

WHILE (@ROWS_INSERTED < @DESIRED_ROW_COUNT)
BEGIN

SET @myCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id FROM MyTable
SET @CURRENT_ROW_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MyTable)

OPEN @myCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @MyId;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            IF ((@CURRENT_SUBMISSION_COUNT < @DESIRED_ROW_COUNT) AND (@ROWS_INSERTED < @DESIRED_ROW_COUNT))
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
                           ([Column1]
                           ([Column2]
                           ([Column3]
                           )

                     SELECT 
                      ,convert(numeric(9,0),rand() * 899999999) + 100000000
                      ,COlumn2
                      ,Colum3
                    FROM MyTable
                    WHERE Id = @MyId

                    SET @NEWLY_INSERTED_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Language]
                               ([MyTable1Id]
                               ,[Target]
                               ,[Source]
                    OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.MyTable1Id, inserted.Source, inserted.[Target] INTO @LANGUAGE_PAIR_IDS (LangugePairId, NewId, SourceLanguage, TargetLangauge)
                    SELECT 
                          @NEWLY_INSERTED_ID
                          ,[Target]
                          ,[Source]
                     FROM [dbo].[Language] 
                     WHERE MyTableId = @MyId
                     ORDER BY Id

                     DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (newLanguageId INT, oldLanguageId INT, sourceLanguage VARCHAR(100), targetLanguage VARCHAR(100))

                     INSERT INTO @tbl (newLanguageId, oldLanguageId, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage)
                     SELECT 0, id, [Source], [Target] MyTable1Id FROM Language WHERE MyTable1Id = @MyId ORDER BY Id

                     UPDATE t
                     SET t.newlanguageid = lp.LangugePairId
                     FROM @tbl t
                     JOIN @LANGUAGE_PAIR_IDS lp
                     ON t.sourceLanguage = lp.SourceLanguage
                     AND t.targetLanguage = lp.TargetLangauge

                     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Manager]
                              ([LanguagePairId]
                              ,[UserId]
                              ,[MyDate])
                     SELECT 
                             tbl.newLanguageId 
                           ,p.[UserId]
                           ,p.[MyDate]
                     FROM Manager m
                     INNER JOIN @tbl tbl
                     ON m.LanguagePairId = tbl.oldLanguageId
                     WHERE m.LanguagePairId in (SELECT Id FROM Language WHERE MyTable1Id = @MyId) -- returns the old language pair id

                     SET @ROWS_INSERTED += 1
                     SET @CURRENT_ROW_COUNT +=1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'REACHED EXIT'
                SET @ROWS_INSERTED = @DESIRED_ROW_COUNT
                BREAK
            END
    FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @MyId;
END
CLOSE @myCursor
DEALLOCATE @myCursor
END
```

The above code works! It generates the data I need. However, it's very very slow. Just to give some comparison. Initial load of data for table 1 was ~60,000 records, Table2: ~74,000 and Tabl3 ~3,400

I tried to insert 9,000 rows in Table1. With the above code, it took 17:05:01 seconds to complete.

Any suggestion on how I can optimize the query to run little faster? My goal is to insert 1-2 mln records in Table1 without having to wait for days. I'm not tied to `CURSOR`. I'm ok to achieve the same result in any other way possible.

Comment: You could use only while loop for insertion, There is no need for cursor

Comment: Can you show an example?